# Spring Boot: Type cannot be null; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type cannot be null when running Stored Procedue

Tags: java, spring-boot

Good morning, I am new to Spring Boot, and I am performing a rest service that must invoke a procedure stored in the database, the question is that you receive the mobile and must return a code and result, as shown below:

[image]

This is my code:

Main Class

```
package com.app.validacion;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package com.app.validacion.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


import com.app.validacion.dao.DriverBonificadosRepository;
import com.app.validacion.entity.RespuestaVo;

@RestController
public class DriverBonificadosController {

    @Autowired
    private DriverBonificadosRepository dao;

    @GetMapping("/service/{movil}")
    public RespuestaVo  ConsultarMovil(@PathVariable String movil) {
        return dao.validarClienteBonifiado(movil);

    }
}
```

Repository

```
package com.app.validacion.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.Procedure;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.app.validacion.entity.DriverBonificados;
import com.app.validacion.entity.RespuestaVo;

public interface DriverBonificadosRepository extends CrudRepository<DriverBonificados, Integer> {

    @Procedure(procedureName="ValidacionClienteBonificado")
    RespuestaVo validarClienteBonifiado(String pMovil);
}
```

My entity

```
import javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery;
import javax.persistence.ParameterMode;
import javax.persistence.StoredProcedureParameter;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
            name="SPValidationClienteBonus4G",
            procedureName="ValidacionClienteBonificado",
            parameters = {
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode=ParameterMode.IN, name="p_movil",type=String.class), 
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode=ParameterMode.OUT, name="code",type=String.class),
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode=ParameterMode.OUT, name="result",type=String.class),
            })

})

@Entity
@Table
public class DriverBonificados {

    @Id
    private int id;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getMovil() {
        return movil;
    }
    public void setMovil(String movil) {
        this.movil = movil;
    }
    public String getContador() {
        return contador;
    }
    public void setContador(String contador) {
        this.contador = contador;
    }
    public Date getFecha_driver() {
        return fecha_driver;
    }
    public void setFecha_driver(Date fecha_driver) {
        this.fecha_driver = fecha_driver;
    }
    public Date getFecha_alta() {
        return fecha_alta;
    }
    public void setFecha_alta(Date fecha_alta) {
        this.fecha_alta = fecha_alta;
    }
    public Date getFecha_fin() {
        return fecha_fin;
    }
    public void setFecha_fin(Date fecha_fin) {
        this.fecha_fin = fecha_fin;
    }
    public Date getCodigo_transaccion() {
        return codigo_transaccion;
    }
    public void setCodigo_transaccion(Date codigo_transaccion) {
        this.codigo_transaccion = codigo_transaccion;
    }
    private String movil;
    private String contador;
    private Date fecha_driver;
    private Date fecha_alta;
    private Date fecha_fin;
    private Date codigo_transaccion;
```

My Class RespuestaVo

```
package com.app.validacion.entity;

public class RespuestaVo {

    private String code;
    private String result;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }
    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

And I get the following error (the mobile parameter must be received as a String, since in the database it is found as Varchar):

[image]

Anyone have an idea how this problem could be solved? I need to consult via Stored Procedue if or if

**UPDATE**

Using @Query and modifying the code as follows:

```
package com.app.validacion.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.Procedure;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import com.app.validacion.entity.DriverBonificados;
import com.app.validacion.entity.RespuestaVo;

public interface DriverBonificadosRepository extends CrudRepository<DriverBonificados, Integer> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true,value = "call ValidacionClienteBonificado(:movil)")
    RespuestaVo validarClienteBonifiado(@Param("movil") String pMovil);
}
```

I get the following error:

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type
>   [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap]
>   to type [com.app.validacion.entity.RespuestaVo]   at
>   org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321)
>   ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194)
>   ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174)
>   ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ProjectingConverter.convert(ResultProcessor.java:297)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.lambda$and$0(ResultProcessor.java:217)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.convert(ResultProcessor.java:228)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor.processResult(ResultProcessor.java:170)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:157)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I managed to solve my problem, using the @Query annotation, and building an interface for the response I was going to receive, in these cases with 2 methods (according to the number of parameters that I will receive), and With this I got my answer in a Json, I leave the interface code below:

```
public interface RespuestaVo {

    String getCode();
    String getResult();

}
```

I recommend using @Query to run Stored Procedue with Spring Boot

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
@GetMapping("/service/{movil}")
public RespuestaVo  ConsultarMovil(@PathVariable("movil") String movil) {
    return dao.validarClienteBonifiado(movil);

}
```